# Flatten Sequence of tuples [(Int, Int), int] in Scala

Tags: scala, flatten

I have this sequence of tuples

```
val data = Seq(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6), ((7,8),9))
```

I want to flatten it to get

```
Seq((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply an anonymous function to shuffle the tuple:

```
val data = Seq(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6), ((7,8),9))
data map { case ((a, b), c) => (a, b, c) }
```

Comment: You concept is good. Your Scala is verbose `data.map{case ((a,b),c)=>(a,b,c)}`

Comment: I knew there was a shorter syntax! Thanks @jwvh

Answer (score 2):

Because the `flatten()` method takes an implicit parameter, you can actually pass explicit instructions on how to flatten you collection.

```
scala> val data = Seq(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6), ((7,8),9))
data: Seq[((Int, Int), Int)] = List(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6), ((7,8),9))

scala> data.flatten{case ((a,b),c) => Seq((a,b,c))}
res0: Seq[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method to transform the tuple, which takes `((X, Y), Z)` and returns `(X, Y, Z)`.

eg.

```
def flattenMe[X, Y, Z](tuple: ((X, Y), Z)): (X, Y, Z) =
      (tuple._1._1, tuple._1._2, tuple._2)
```

or, you can pass the sequence itself and flatten each tuple.

```
  it("flattens me to single tuple"){

    def flattMe[X, Y, Z](sequence: Seq[((X, Y), Z)]) : Seq[(X, Y, Z)] =
          sequence.map { case ((x, y), z) => (x, y, z)}

    val data = flattMe(Seq(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6), ((7,8),9)))

    assert(data.head == (1, 2, 3))
    assert(data(1) == (4, 5, 6))
    assert(data(2) == (7, 8, 9))

  }
```

Comment: Apply an anonymous function to shuffle the tuple:

    val data = Seq(((1,2),3), ((4,5),6), ((7,8),9))
    data map (x => x match { case ((a, b), c) => (a, b, c) })

Comment: Thats beautiful @MarvinSielenkemper, would recommend to post as answer. I like that better :)

Comment: Whoa ... that was supposed to be an answer. And I am wondering why the formatting does not work as expected... silly me.
Oh, and thanks :)

Comment: if `flattenMe` be made `implicit` it would look natural, won't it?